# Сохранение данных из API в localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуете уважаемые разработчики. Я вытаскиваю данные из API и загружаю на html страницу. Это что-то типа виджета погоды, вы можете в инпуте написать город и вам выдаст инфу по погоде. Способ элементарный, но мне надо сохранить данные после обновления страницы, надо чтобы все оставалось так, как и было до обновления. Например: я написал в графу поиска город "Москва", мне все выдало, обновляю страницу и html файл не меняется. Я понимаю, что это можно сделать через локал сторэдж или сессион сторэдж, я прочитал документацию и посмотрел ролики, но не знаю как поступать в моем случае. Хотелось бы получить код с объяснением. Заранее вам спасибо

```js
function search(){
    fetch('https://goweather.herokuapp.com/weather/'+city.value)
.then(function (resp) {return resp.json()})
.then (function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    document.querySelector('.cityText').innerHTML = city.value
    document.querySelector('.temp').innerHTML = data.temperature
    document.querySelector('.descr').innerHTML = data.description
    document.querySelector('.wind').innerHTML = data.wind
    var back = document.querySelector('.viget')
    var temp = data.temperature.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '')//убираем в графе температура всё, кроме минуса и цифр
    temp = Number(temp)//меняем тип данных у температуры из string в number
    if (temp>20){
        back.style.background = "#FFFFCC";
       }
    else if (0<=temp<=20){
        back.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
       }
    if (temp<0){
        back.style.background = "#CCFFFF";
       }
})
  
}
var city = document.querySelector('.city')
```

```css
.container{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
margin: 0 auto;
justify-content: center;
}
.viget{
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #d31a48;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
.temp{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.second{
   margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <input class = "city" type="text"> <button onclick="search()">Узнать погоду</button>
        <div class = "viget">
            <div class = "first">
                <p class = "cityText"></p>
                <p class = "temp"></p> 
            </div>
            <div class = "second">
                <p class = "descr"></p>
                <p class = "wind"></p>
             </div>
            
        </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению здесь работать не будет, поэтому просто скопируйте и проверьте у себя на устройстве. Более подробно почитать про localStorage можно [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```js
function search() {
  fetch('https://goweather.herokuapp.com/weather/' + city.value)
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      
      if(data.message === 'NOT_FOUND'){
        // тут следует дописать какое-либо сообщение пользователю, чтобы было понятно, что произошло
        return;
      }
      
      //Добавили значение в localStorage.
      localStorage.setItem('weather', city.value)
      
      document.querySelector('.cityText').innerHTML = city.value
      document.querySelector('.temp').innerHTML = data.temperature
      document.querySelector('.descr').innerHTML = data.description
      document.querySelector('.wind').innerHTML = data.wind
      var back = document.querySelector('.viget')
      var temp = data.temperature.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '') //убираем в графе температура всё, кроме минуса и цифр
      temp = Number(temp) //меняем тип данных у температуры из string в number
      if (temp > 20) {
        back.style.background = "#FFFFCC";
      } else if (0 <= temp <= 20) {
        back.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
      }
      if (temp < 0) {
        back.style.background = "#CCFFFF";
      }
    })
}

const city = document.querySelector('.city');

// Если что-то есть в localStorage, то установим в значение инпута.
const localQuery = localStorage.getItem('weather');
city.value = localQuery !== null ? localQuery : '';
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.viget {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #d31a48;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.temp {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.second {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input class="city" type="text"> <button onclick="search()">Узнать погоду</button>
    <div class="viget">
      <div class="first">
        <p class="cityText"></p>
        <p class="temp"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="second">
        <p class="descr"></p>
        <p class="wind"></p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: SaNFeeD Данные сохраняются в инпут, разве нельзя сохранить данные, которые показались на html  странице?

Comment: Конечно можно. Полученный массив переделываете в json с помощью  JSON.stringify(data), затем полученный json добавляете в localStorage с помощью localStorage.setItem('weather', json). 
И теперь при каждой загрузки страницы делать проверку на наличие данных в localStorage при помощи localStorage.getItem('weather') !== null. Если данные есть, то поступаете с ними также, как и с теми, что приходят к вам от сервера. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил

Comment: Спасибо, всё сохранил, а вот задний фон как сохранить? Оно не хочет(( Можете просто пример кода написать маленький, с объяснением, а дальше я сам разберусь)

Comment: А как может задний фон не сохраниться? У вас, судя по коду, он просто достается из data.temperature и затем в этот цвет окрашивается div. Дополните вопрос, вашим кодом.

Comment: Всё сохранил, просто рано задал вопрос, простите

Comment: Все заработало? Если помог, то отметьте вопрос - как решенный